# DNN 9.2 Pages Management

Tags: dotnetnuke

I recently upgraded 8 websites to DNN v. 09.02.02 (178), one of them is the host/main site and has additional menu options.  On this site I am unable to edit pages, you can open the Pages list and see the pages but when you click on one all you get is an error (An error has occurred) so you cant get to the page properties.  I need to change permissions and delete a page but am unable to do so.  The other 7 websites all work fine in this regard. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you navigate to a page, put it in Edit mode, and click the edit page (gear) icon at the bottom?

I've not encountered any problems editing pages in 9.2.2.  I think that they were all upgraded from earlier 9.x or a clean 9.2.2 install.  From which version of DNN did you upgrade?

Are there any errors in the Admin Log (Event Log)?  Or in the /Portals/a_default/logs directory?

Comment: What happens if you navigate to a page, put it in Edit mode, and click the edit page (gear) icon at the bottom?  - The page manager loads and then I get the same error.

Comment: Can you paste the error?  Look in the Event Log for details.

Comment: Message:StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex

StackTrace:

at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) at Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes.Components.ThemesController.CreateThumbnail(String strImage) at Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes.Components.ThemesController.GetThemes(ThemeType type, String strRoot) at Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes.Components.ThemesController.GetLayouts(PortalSettings portalSettings, ThemeLevel level) at Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes.Components....